# Files in secondary partition are invisible

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, windows-explorer

I've recently worked on my sister's computer which had been "broken" by one of her sons.

I backed up some important data on another computer (win10), and proceeded to reinstall windows 10 on the computer. I set up two separate partitions, one of 150GB for the system and programs, and one of ~1.3TB for storing files.

I copied the backed up data on the second partition. Unfortunately, after putting the hard drive back in her computer, I cannot see the files.

The files are not hidden in the standard meaning of it. Hidden files are set to be showned in explorer's options.
In the partition's properties, the used space matches precisely the amount of data I've copied.

Here's an image to help with my explanation :

[image: uytu]

I've tried putting the hard drive back in the second computer, to no avail (same problem).
I've also tried booting on a linux rescue USB drive. All I can see in the partition are two folders "$RECYCLE_BIN" and "System Volume Information".

To my great shame, I used cut/paste instead of copy/paste so the data is no longer available on the second computer.

I'm hoping someone might know how to access/save these files.

Thanks.

EDIT : The top red square reads "The folder is empty", and the bottom one reads "Allocated space:   99 448 250 368 bytes    92.8GB".
If anything else needs to be translated or specified, please let me know.

Comment: I think the files have been deleted if you can't see them in linux. Try recovery using Recuva. https://www.piriform.com/recuva

Comment: Looks like you don't even have permissions to view the files.  Have you tried to recursively change the ownership of all files on the drives through the property window? I can't read the text in the screenshot so I cannot provide more specific instructions or even an answer.  You should address that problem.

Comment: @Ramhound: I've just tried changing the ownership, but it didn't help. As for screenshot text, I've edited my OP. Let me know if you need anything else translated, or any other kind of information.

Comment: Provide us the ACL information for the folder in question.  You can blank out any usernames that might indicate your actual name if you want.  Just leave the security information for said user visible.

Answer (score 0):

Your partition reports the used space, it means most likely file are registered in $MFT, but you don't have permission to List/View files under the root directory (S:).

Open `cmd` as an admin and run:

```
takeown /F S:\ /R /D Y
icacls S:\ /grant "USER":F /T
```

Where **USER** can be one of the following:

- **%UserName%**: To grant access to current Admin running the `cmd`.
- **Administrators**: To grant access to all Administrators.
- **Everyone**: To grant access to everyone with a user account on the computer.
- **Authenticated Users**: Same as above.
- **Users**: Same as bove.

Answer (score -1):

If you have any Linux experience, you could boot a live Linux CD (such as Knoppix), and then mount both partitions and do a directory listing.  If you don't see anything, then the files have most likely been deleted.  You might still have some luck with an undelete utility, but those are never completely reliable.  If you DO see your files, I would copy them to another disk (like a portable hard drive or something).  Then you could reformat re-install, then copy the files back when Windows is running again.

Comment: As mentionned in my message, I've already tried to save the files using linux but even there they won't appear. I will try my luck with recuva if I have no other/better alternative, though. Thanks.